# How to count files in FTP directory

Tags: powershell, ftp, ftpwebrequest, split

I have this script. I'm trying to count how many file are in.

```powershell
clear
$ftp_uri = "ftp://ftp.domain.net:"
$user = "username"
$pass = "password"
$subfolder = "/test/out/"
$ftp_urix = $ftp_uri + $subfolder
$uri=[system.URI] $ftp_urix

$ftp=[system.net.ftpwebrequest]::Create($uri)

$ftp.Credentials=New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)

#Get a list of files in the current directory.
$ftp.Method=[system.net.WebRequestMethods+ftp]::ListDirectorydetails
$ftp.UseBinary = $true
$ftp.KeepAlive = $false
$ftp.EnableSsl = $true
$ftp.Timeout = 30000
$ftp.UsePassive=$true

try
{
 $ftpresponse=$ftp.GetResponse()
 $strm=$ftpresponse.GetResponseStream()
 $ftpreader=New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($strm,'UTF-8')
 $list=$ftpreader.ReadToEnd()

 $lines=$list.Split("`n")

 $lines
 $lines.Count

 $ftpReader.Close() 
 $ftpresponse.Close()
}
catch{
 $_|fl * -Force
 $ftpReader.Close() 
 $ftpresponse.Close()
}
```

In the directory I have three files but `$lines.count` return 4. `$lines` have 4 rows, three files and an empty line. Somebody can explain me the mystery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$list` contains:

```
file1`nfile2`nfile3`n
```

If you split the string by "`n", you (correctly) get four parts, with the last one being empty.

You can use an [overload of `String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split#system-string-split(system-string-system-stringsplitoptions)) that takes [`StringSplitOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions) and use `RemoveEmptyEntries`:

```powershell
$list.Split("`n", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```